XML/XSLT: Style similar tagging scenarios differently
I have two scenarios where I use the <b> tag within a <p> tag in XML:

The <p> tag contains plain text and an occasional <b> tag (typical use):

<p>This is a sentence with a <b>bold</b> word.</p>


The <p> tag only contains the <b> tag:

<p><b>This is a subsection title</b></p>

Can I use XSLT 2.0 to change the font size of the <b> tag in scenario 2 only?
I'm aware that I could easily use the outputclass attribute and style with CSS, but long story short, this isn't sufficient for my needs.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

A template matching p[not(text())]/b will process only those b elements that do not have any sibling text nodes.

And match="p[count(child::node())=1]/b" will process only those b` elements that do not have any siblings of any kind.

To account for possible insignificant whitespace, I'd use p[not(text()[normalize-space()])]/b

@DanielHaley If such scenario is anticipated, it would be simpler to use xsl:strip-space.

Without more of what you tried and where the challenge lies the most succinct is probably to just add the style attribute.  Thus here I will only give you fragments that you might use for the style attribute and ways to not select nodes that have non-whitespace siblings.
<xsl:attribute name="style">
   <xsl:value-of select="'font-size:3em;'"/>
</xsl:attribute>

As for how to select that it is not easily discerned without more of the XML (HTML) you are attempting to update nor fix what you have not posted in you XSLT.
<xsl:template match="p/b">
  <xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat('font-size: ', '3em', 'em;')"/>
</xsl:template>

preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()[normalize-space()='')][1][self::text()] should suffice to check that the first preceding sibling node that is not a whitespace text node is a text node
Whitespace such as new lines and the indents are their own text node so you may need something like this added to your stylesheet for that.
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

